# Sends files from client to server

Tags: java, io, ftp, client-server, file-transfer

In the below codes,I am trying to let the server-side to select the file from the client and sends it, so basically all the work is done on the server side. the program works by running the server first wait for client to run, make a connection, then the server sends the place of the file to the client-side  `outReader.write("B://ghassar/ghassar.txt");` the client reads the location and sends the file. I have run  the debug and once the server  reads this code        `String filename = inReader.readLine();` it stops and it gets in like a loop, can anyone help me to solve the problem

```
/ Server.java

/*
 * Server waits for a connection to be established by client
 *
 */

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Server
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Server running...");

        /* Listen on port 5555 */

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(222);

        /* Accept the sk */

        Socket sk = server.accept();

        System.out.println("Server accepted client");
        // to recive from client
        InputStream input = sk.getInputStream();
        //read what is coming
        BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));
        //write to client
        BufferedWriter outReader = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sk.getOutputStream()));
            outReader.write("B://ghassar/ghassar.txt");
            outReader.flush();
        /* Read the filename */
        String filename = inReader.readLine();

        if (filename.equals("ghassar.txt") ){

            /* Reply back to client with READY status */

            outReader.write("READY\n");
            outReader.flush();
        }

        /* Create a new file in the libya directory using the filename */
        FileOutputStream wr = new FileOutputStream(new File("B://libya/ "+ filename));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[sk.getReceiveBufferSize()];

        int bytesReceived = 0;

        while((bytesReceived = input.read(buffer))>0)
        {
            /* Write to the file */
           wr.write(buffer,0,bytesReceived);
        }
    }
}


import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client  {
    public static void main(String args[]){



        Client clientForm = new Client();
        clientForm.action();

    }
    public void action() {


        try{

            /* Try to connect to the server on localhost, port 5555 */

            Socket sk = new Socket("localhost", 222);
            OutputStream output = sk.getOutputStream();

            /* the steam to send the staff*/

            OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(sk.getOutputStream());

            /* steam to recive staff */

            BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));

               String serverStatus = inReader.readLine(); // Read the first line
               String filename =  serverStatus;//fileDlg.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
               outputStream.write("ghassar.txt");
               outputStream.flush();

            /* If server is ready, send the file */

            if ( serverStatus.equals("READY") ){

                FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filename);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[sk.getSendBufferSize()];

                int bytesRead = 0;

                while((bytesRead = file.read(buffer))>0)
                {
                    output.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
                }

                output.close();
                file.close();
                sk.close();
               System.out.println("File sent");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            /* Catch any errors */
                 System.out.println("not File sent");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) instead of `BufferedWriter`. There is no need to call flush after each line and simply use `println()` method along with **auto-flush** feature to add a new line as well.

> Unlike the PrintStream class, if automatic flushing is enabled it will be done only when one of the `println`, `printf`, or `format` methods is invoked, rather than whenever a newline character happens to be output.
>
> These methods use the platform's own notion of line separator rather than the newline character.

There is no need to append `\n` in the message itself.

Sample code:

```
// here true means auto flush when `println()` method is called
PrintWriter w=new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sk.getOutputStream()),true);
w.println(message);
```

---

Possible cause in the code:

The problem may be at below lines where `\n` is not added in the end of the string in `write()` method before flushing and at client side the method `readLine()` is used to read it.

```
BufferedWriter outReader = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sk.getOutputStream()));
outReader.write("B://ghassar/ghassar.txt"); 
outReader.flush();
```

**Note:** you can use [BufferedWriter#newLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine%28%29) instead of `\n` that writes a line separator. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline (`'\n'`) character.